# Valgrind error m64 m32

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to verify this code file test.c below using valgrind, when I make  gcc test.c -o test I get the follow error

```
Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==22765==    at 0x4F22870: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==22765==    by 0x4EB0002: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1261)
==22765==    by 0x4EB14DB: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:538)
==22765==    by 0x4EB0D5F: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:165)
==22765==    by 0x4EA4B0F: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:59)
==22765==    by 0x400986: main (in /home/grados-sanchez/git/merkle-codigos-C/test)
==22765==  Address 0x4025770 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22765==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==22765==    at 0x4007E2: node_write (in /home/grados-sanchez/git/merkle-codigos-C/test)
```

but when I run gcc test.c -o test and then valgrind I don't get any error. My question is What happen with valgrind in this case? Is there any way for run valgrind for 32 or 64 bits?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define id_lenght 6000
typedef unsigned char * ustring;
typedef struct {
    ustring ustr;
    int height;
    char id[id_lenght];
} node;

int validation_read(void * ptr_var, size_t sizeof_datatype, int num,
    FILE * ptr_file) {
    if (fread(ptr_var, sizeof_datatype, num, ptr_file) <= 0) {
        printf("Error reading file");
       return 1;
    }
return 0;
}

void node_read(FILE * node_ptr, node * n, int r) {
    int i;
    validation_read(n->id, sizeof(unsigned char), id_lenght, node_ptr);
    validation_read(&(n->height), sizeof(int), 1, node_ptr);
    validation_read(n->ustr, sizeof(unsigned char) * (r + 1), 1,node_ptr);
}

void node_init(node * n, int r) {
    memset(n, 0, sizeof(node));
    n->ustr = malloc((r + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    memset(n->ustr, 0, (r + 1));
    n->ustr[r] = 0;
    n->height = -1;
    memset(n->id,0,id_lenght+1);
}


void node_write(FILE * node_ptr, node * n, int r) {
    int i;
    char newid[id_lenght];
    memset(newid,0,id_lenght);
    sprintf(newid,"%s",n->id);
    fwrite(newid, sizeof(char), id_lenght+1, node_ptr);
    fwrite(&(n->height), sizeof(int), 1, node_ptr);
    fwrite(n->ustr, sizeof(unsigned char) * (r + 1), 1,node_ptr);
}


void node_destroy(node * n) {
    free(n->ustr);
    n->height = -1;
}

int main(){
    FILE * ptr = fopen("juantest","w+");
    int r = 64/8;
    node in;
    node_init(&in, r);
    node_write(ptr, &in, r);
    node_destroy(&in);
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

**EDIT**
But a problem happens when I trying to read the file. I edited my above code. I get Error reading fileError reading fileError reading

Comment: Your code is not readable, please format it.! And `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Comment: Your "Error reading file" appearing 3 times must mean there is nothing *written* in the file, or you are writing to the file and immediately try to read from it.

Comment: in function: node_read() and in function: node_write():  each of these functions has a variable on the stack: 'i' that is not used.  Suggest 1) remove those two variables.  2) enable all warnings when compiling and fix those warnings (afterall, the compiler knows the C language a lot better than you or I do.)

Comment: 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful 2) the typedef for ustring hides the underlying type.  suggest using unsigned char and eliminating the typedef.  3) a struct should not be typedef'd.  It just clutters the code, leads to mis-understandings and clutters the compiler name space.  Use a struct tagname to make the code much easier to understand.

Comment: 1) the call to fread(), when there is an error, should tell the user all the available info.  Suggest, rather than using a 'printf()' use 'perror()'  2) when #define'ing a numeric value, always surround the value by parens so there is no 'text replacement' errors

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in the function: node_init(), this line: 'n->ustr[r] = 0;' is not needed as the call to memset() already set all the bytes to 0

Comment: this line: 'memset(n->id,0,id_lenght+1);' is invoking undefined behavior because it is accessing a byte beyond the end of the n->id buffer, which can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: this line: 'fwrite(newid, sizeof(char), id_lenght+1, node_ptr);' is accessing a byte beyond the end of the id[] buffer, causing undefined behavior.. which can/will result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valgrind is right to worry. In this line

```
fwrite(newid, sizeof(char), id_lenght+1, node_ptr);
```

you are writing 1 byte more data than allowed; the one *beyond* your new temporary stack string. You probably confused writing a string (with a `+1` for the terminating zero) with writing exactly the (maximum) buffer size used:

```
fwrite(newid, sizeof(char), id_length, node_ptr);
```

Since you are dumping memory contents to a file, you are correct to clear the string memory before using `sprintf`. You never know what's inside freshly allocated memory!
Note that if you are worried about data integrity, it's always better to use the safe variant `sprintf_s` instead, as it will guard you from over-running this buffer.

Comment: but I want to write a fixed lenght array newid

Comment: @Juan: fair point (and I was wondering how you'd read that string back!). Inverted my answer, and a +1 for you for clearing the string before writing to disk. But look into the `_s` functions for safety. Also please use ALL_CAPS for `#define`s - it's a convention but a pretty strong one.

Comment: @Juan: yes I noticed. That is actually a new problem, and so your question has changed. Please try to avoid that.